# How to display only part of the format-table column entries?

Tags: powershell

I'm getting appointments from MS outlook using powershell. I'm at the point where i have all appointments from the last two weeks. Output goes into a format-table for now. 
However, i want to do some further processing using information in one of the columns of the table.

I have the following object with appointments as output. The subject column is the subject field of an outlook appointment:

```
Subject                           Start
------                            ------
Token1, Token2, Token3, Token4    6/11/2013 9:00:00 AM   
Token1, Token2, Token3, Token4    6/11/2013 9:00:00 AM
```

I only want to display Token2 and Token4 from the Subject column/property and use those individually at a later time. The tokens contain different patterns, split by commas.

What would be the best approach here? Split? Trim?

Get-OutlookCalendar will generate my object as displayed in the above code block. I need to take the complete string "Token1, Token2, Token3, Token4" for each entry and convert it to a object looking like this:

```
Subject          Start
------            ------
Token2, Token4    6/11/2013 9:00:00 AM   
Token2, Token4    6/11/2013 9:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipe to `Select-Object` not to `Format-Table`. That way you'll end up with real object that you can further manipulate and not with formatting instructions objects that are used to instruct PowerShell how to display the objects in the console..

Comment: allright, i'll do that. But can you guide me a little further on the "manipulating" part to achieve what i described in my question?

Comment: You need to show more code. The command that created the objects and so on. In a nutshell something like: ... | select start,@{n='Subject';e={$_.Subject -notmatch 'Token[24]'}}

Comment: i dont have that much code yet. So when piping to select, i can adjust the output of the subject column to only "Token2" and "Token4"?

Comment: To be more clear: i want to be able to only display Token2 and Token4 in my subject column. So basically, stripping the subject string

Comment: You need to construct a working code example we can all refer to, otherwise it would be very hard to help you.

Comment: I'd love to, but i don't have a working example, hence the question. I don't know what to do with the object to be able to strip some part of the subject string and have a new object with only token2 and token4 in the subject string. I've edited the original question to explain better